# CSS: Why won't these buttons take the fixed width and height I set?

Tags: html, css, button, height, width

I'm trying to make [these](https://jsfiddle.net/Sapotick/aphc2bju/1/) buttons a fixed size. Which is width 42px and height 25px. For some reason, they aren't the correct size. Just the standard one. I've looked for solutions but couldn't find one sadly. Sorry if my code is a bit messy, I'm a beginner and trying to make something work :)

Here is the HTML and CSS code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Super epic game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainstyles.css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.45"> 
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
        <div id="speelkader"> <canvas  id="canvas" style="background-color: black;"></canvas></div>
        <div id="attributen">
                <button id="rood" class="color-changer" data-color="red">Rood</button>
                <button id="groen" class="color-changer" data-color="green">Groen</button>
                <button id="blauw" class="color-changer" data-color="blue">Blauw</button>
                <button id="paars" class="color-changer" data-color="purple">Paars</button>
                <button id="oranje" class="color-changer" data-color="orange">Oranje</button>
                <button id="geel" class="color-changer" data-color="yellow">Geel</button>
                <button id="wit" class="color-changer" data-color="white">Wit</button>
                <button id="gum" class="color-changer" data-color="black">Gum</button>
                <input type="button" id="reset" value="Reset tekening" onClick="window.location.reload()">
                <div id="clear"></div>
        </div>
</div>




<p id="center">Hallo! Gebruik de WASD toetsen om te bewegen :)</p>




<script src="gameJS.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
* 
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container{
    width: 1359px;
    margin: auto;
}
#speelkader{ 

    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: transparent;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

#attributen{
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
    width: 500px;
    height: 800px;
    float: left;
}

#clear {
    clear: both;
}

canvas{
    background-color: black;
    height: 800px;
    width:  800px;
}


#groen{
    background-color: green; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#groen:hover{
    background-color:darkgreen; 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#rood{
    background-color: red; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;       
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#rood:hover{
    background-color:darkred; 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#blauw{
    background-color: blue; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#blauw:hover{
    background-color:darkblue; 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#paars{
    background-color: purple; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;   
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#paars:hover{
    background-color:rgb(92, 0, 92); 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#oranje{
    background-color: orange; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#oranje:hover{
    background-color:darkorange; 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#geel{
    background-color: yellow; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#geel:hover{
    background-color:rgb(233, 233, 0); 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#wit{
    background-color: white; 
    color: black;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#wit:hover{
    background-color: whitesmoke; 
    color: black;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#gum{
    background-color: gray; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#gum:hover{
    background-color: darkgray; 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}

#reset{
    background-color: darkred; 
    color: white;
    width: 42px;
    height: 25px;   
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.1s;
    font-family: Lato;
    border-color: black;
    border-style: solid;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#reset:hover{
    background-color: rgb(114, 0, 0); 
    color: white;        
    transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

Comment: As per the link you shared, your buttons are 45 pixels wide and 25 pixels tall. What's the problem?

Comment: @BlackWiCKED well my fault, that was pretty stupid. I changed it back so that the font-size determined the size of the button. Buttons were uneven so I went with a fixed size and those were smaller than the font so yeah... You probably don't understand what I'm saying but its fine because its fixed now :)

Comment: Well I'm trying to understand... :) You can play with the overflow property, so the text won't change the dimensions of the button. Suggestion: Instead of using separate ID for each button in your CSS (#groen, #rood, etc..) add a new class to each button (.customButton) and change all the elements simultaneously. You can remove lot of duplicate lines that way and it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used separated id in styles for width and height and removed it all used ID height and width. Use the below code and it will work equal height and width for the button.

```
#attributen button[class=color-changer], 
  #attributen input[id="reset"] {    
    width: 140px;    
    height: 35px;
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add button type attributes with all the buttons and set it to button, your problem will get solve.

```
type="button"
```